# Wordpress sort custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom post type which displays all my entires upside down, meaning the first entrie is displayed last on my actual front page - is there a way to change the sort order?

My code is as follows:

```
        <?php global $post; ?>

        <ul class="menu-items">
            <?php
            $menuloop = new WP_Query(array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type'      => 'menu',
                'tax_query'      => array(
                    // Note: tax_query expects an array of arrays!
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'menu_type', // my guess
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $menuname_category
                    )
                ),
            ));

            ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( $menuloop->have_posts() ) : $menuloop->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                    <div class="grid2column"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                    <div class="grid2column lastcolumn"><?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'menuoption_menu_pricing', true)): ?><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'menuoption_menu_pricing', true) ?><?php endif; ?></div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="item-description-menu"><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is an error in the code you have given in the question. `posts_per_page => -1`.

Why would it be `-1`? It has to be a number `> 0` for something to display.

For sorting you need to add these two arguments to the array

`array ( 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC'`

Basically, you can change the `DESC` to `ASC` to reverse the order.

### Final array

```
$menuloop = new WP_Query(array(
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'post_type'      => 'menu',
                'orderby'        => 'date', // new arg
                'order'          => 'DESC', // new arg
                'tax_query'      => array(
                    // Note: tax_query expects an array of arrays!
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'menu_type', // my guess
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => $menuname_category
                    )
                ),
            ));
```

Comment: For future reference, -1 as a posts_per_page value is set to mean No Limit. It is not an error.